# '=': cannot convert from 'int' to 'std::_Iosb<int>::_Fmtflags'

Tags: c++, c++17, boost-multiprecision

Trying to use ios format flags to format the string representation of Boost multiprecision cpp_int.
Everything works with gcc standard c++17, but in Visual Studio 2019 (v142) same standard, I'm getting a compilation error when using '|' operator to combine flags:

```
string format_cpp_int(boost::multiprecision::cpp_int& n, bool show_base, bool uppercase)
{
    auto f = std::ios::hex;
    if (show_base) f = f | std::ios::showbase;
    if (uppercase) f = f | std::ios::uppercase;
    return n.str(0, f);
}
```

Getting the following error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   C2440   '=': cannot convert from 'int' to 'std::_Iosb::_Fmtflags' (compiling source file main.cpp)

Is there some difference between c++17 support in gcc and VS that i'm not aware of?

Also trying to cast the result back to fmtflags doesn't seem to work either.

```
f = static_cast<std::ios::fmtflags>(f | std::ios::showbase);
```

is there another way to combine the flags and pass to cpp_int?

Answer (score 0):

Because the keyword `auto` may get the underlying type, which may be implemented by the specific compiler.

You should write the type immediately:

```
std::ios::fmtflags f = std::ios::hex;
if (show_base) f = f | std::ios::showbase;
if (uppercase) f = f | std::ios::uppercase;
```